# Programmatically setting an org-mode heading

Tags: org-mode

There exist functions to set tags, keywords, and priority values (`org-set-tags-to`, `org-todo`, and `org-priority` respectively), but what about setting the heading (item) itself?

For example:

```
*** TODO [#B] Some existing heading                      :URGENT:
```

`(my/org-set-heading "The new heading")`

```
*** TODO [#B] The new heading                            :URGENT:
```

Setting the heading is non-trivial; the logic needs to be mindful of outline folding, heading stars, the priority label, and tags-- at the very least.  Is there an org function that accomplishes this (or a 3rd-party library that includes one)?

I haven't found any org functions that accomplish this, but my *apropos-fu* has certainly failed me before.

A fairly thorough search suggests that I'll need to employ `org-complex-heading-regexp`, special care to the subtree/folding, and possibly a patch request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to get there with org-dp (https://github.com/tj64/org-dp, and its on MELPA):

```
(require 'org-dp)

(let ((hl (progn
        (outline-previous-heading)
        (org-element-context))))

  (org-dp-rewire
   nil ;; type.
   (buffer-substring (org-element-property :contents-begin hl)
             (org-element-property :contents-end hl))
   t ;; replace
   '(:title "new headline")
   hl))
```

You could wrap this in a function that sets the title to what you want. I think org-dp-rewire is what you want.

Comment: This does the trick in setting the heading, but creates an issue of its own.  It inserts an org 'NAME' keyword (`#+NAME: `) line immediately before the modified heading.  Do you observe this same behavior?

Comment: no I don't see that. I am using org 9, and org-dp from MELPA today.

Comment: I just noticed if the headline has a NAME property then I see that. I am not sure what to do about that. Maybe raise it as an issue with org-dp.

Comment: Nice catch!  I was in the process of upgrading to 9 and hadn't started troubleshooting yet.  Indeed the headings have "name" properties.  I'll create an issue on org-dp.  The org name keyword probably needs a prefixed syntax in org-dp.

Answer (score 7):

Out of the box `org-mode` provides a function called `org-edit-headline`, which changes the title and doesn't mess with todo state, priority or tags.

```
(org-edit-headline "The new heading")
```

Hope it helps.